# How to remove "isCustom" key value pair from following JSON

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

For example I receive a JSON response from postman and store it in a variable. How can I remove a specific key from this response?

{"editdata":[{"A11":"T55","ID":"4","FVAModifiedDateLongValues":"3:1334835002030","ModifiedDateLongValue":1614614214967,"F033":[{"Name":"p3","Type":"String","Values":null,"Description":"p3","isCustom":false},{"Name":"p3","Type":"String","Values":null,"Description":"p3","isCustom":false}],"flag":"edit"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just iterate over the array with the objects you want to delete, and delete the field from each object using the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

```js
let myObject = {
    "editdata": [{
        "A11": "T55",
        "ID": "4",
        "FVAModifiedDateLongValues": "3:1334835002030",
        "ModifiedDateLongValue": 1614614214967,
        "F033": [{
          "Name": "p3",
          "Type": "String",
          "Values": null,
          "Description": "p3",
          "isCustom": false
        }, {
          "Name": "p3",
          "Type": "String",
          "Values": null,
          "Description": "p3",
          "isCustom": false
        }],
        "flag": "edit"}]
    };
// if you want to delete it for all objects in the editdata array, you could do a nested forEach.
myObject.editdata[0].F033.forEach(obj => delete obj.isCustom);
console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: Thank you, please share how to remove multiple key value pairs 
for example if I want to remove isComplex,description,values all three key value pairs

Comment: Just add curly functions to the forEach function body, and add multiple delete statements: `myObject.editdata[0].F033.forEach(obj => {delete obj.isCustom; delete obj.description; });`

Comment: Thank you for helping